# Spinner - Выбор позиции по умолчанию из SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, android-spinner

Есть Spinner который формируется с помощью SimpleCursorAdapter

```
//Формируем столбцы 
String[] from = new String[]{db.CATEGORY_TABLE_NAME};
// создаем адаптер и настраиваем список
Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "ChangeTask - spinnerInstall - Создаем адаптер и настраиваем список");
scAdapterSpinner = new SimpleCursorAdapter(ChangeTask.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, null, from, new int[]{android.R.id.text1}, 0);
scAdapterSpinner.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
//Присваиваем спинеру Адаптер
spinner.setAdapter(scAdapterSpinner);
```

Мне необходимо указать позицию по умолчанию, spinner.setSelection() - не работает, с АрейАдаптером работал, а тут нет. Как можно реализовать установку Спиннера по умолчанию если он формируется с помощью SimpleCursorAdapter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разобрался сам.
Суть в том что строчку **spinner.setSelection(num);** надо ставить не сразу после **spinner.setAdapter(scAdapterSpinner);** а в том месте где адаптер устанавливает курсор

```
//Присвоили адаптеру курсор
scAdapterSpinner.swapCursor(cursor)
//Установили в нужную позицию
spinner.setSelection(num);
```